# How to remove a URL monitoring while script is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have written a script where I am doing a monitor on some webpages and whenever there is a specific html tag found, it should print a notification. The point is to run the script 24/7 and while the script is running, I want to remove URL. I have currently a database where I am going to read the URLS that is being found/removed.

```
import threading

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Replacement for database for now
URLS = [
    'https://github.com/search?q=hello+world',
    'https://github.com/search?q=python+3',
    'https://github.com/search?q=world',
    'https://github.com/search?q=i+love+python',
]


def doRequest(url):
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

            if soup.find("span", {"data-search-type": "Repositories"}).text.strip():  # if there are sizes
                sendNotifications({
                    'title': soup.find("input", {"name": "q"})['value'],
                    'repo_count': soup.find("span", {"data-search-type": "Repositories"}).text.strip()
                })
        else:
            print(url, response.status_code)


def sendNotifications(data):
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # TODO read URLS from database instead of lists
    for url in URLS:
        threading.Thread(target=doRequest, args=(url,)).start()
```

The current problem im facing is that the `doRequest` is in a while loop which is running all the time and I wonder how can I remove a specific URL while the script is running inside a runnable script? e.g. `https://github.com/search?q=world`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: A simple approach**

What you want is to insert some termination logic in the `while True` loop so that it constantly checks for a termination signal.

To this end, you can use `threading.Event()`.

For example, you can add a `stopping_event` argument:

```
def doRequest(url, stopping_event):
    while True and not stopping_event.is_set():
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

            if soup.find("span", {"data-search-type": "Repositories"}).text.strip():  # if there are sizes
                sendNotifications({
                    'title': soup.find("input", {"name": "q"})['value'],
                    'repo_count': soup.find("span", {"data-search-type": "Repositories"}).text.strip()
                })
        else:
            print(url, response.status_code)
```

And you create these events when starting the threads

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # TODO read URLS from database instead of lists
    stopping_events = {url: threading.Event() for url in URLS}

    for url in URLS:
        threading.Thread(target=doRequest, args=(url, stopping_events[url])).start()
```

Whenever you want to stop/remove a particular url, you can just call

```
stopping_events[url].set()
```

That particular `while` loop will stop and exit.

You can even create a separate thread that waits for an user input to stop a particular url:

```
def manager(stopping_events):
    while True:
        url = input('url to stop: ')
        if url in stopping_events:
            stopping_events[url].set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # TODO read URLS from database instead of lists
    stopping_events = {url: threading.Event() for url in URLS}

    for url in URLS:
        threading.Thread(target=doRequest, args=(url, stopping_events[url])).start()
    threading.Thread(target=manager, args=(stopping_events,)).start()
```

---

**Method 2: A cleaner approach**

Instead of having a fixed list of URLs, you can have a thread that keeps reading the list of URLs and feed it to the processing threads. This is the Producer-Consumer pattern. Now you don't really remove any URL. You simply keep processing the later list of URLs from the database. That should automatically take care of newly added/deleted URLs.

```
import queue
import threading

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Replacement for database for now
def get_urls_from_db(q: queue.Queue):
    while True:
        url_list = ...  # some db read logic
        map(q.put, url_list)  # putting newly read URLs into queue

def doRequest(q: queue.Queue):
    while True:
        url = q.get()  # waiting and getting url from queue
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

            if soup.find("span", {"data-search-type": "Repositories"}).text.strip():  # if there are sizes
                sendNotifications({
                    'title': soup.find("input", {"name": "q"})['value'],
                    'repo_count': soup.find("span", {"data-search-type": "Repositories"}).text.strip()
                })
        else:
            print(url, response.status_code)


def sendNotifications(data):
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # TODO read URLS from database instead of lists
    url_queue = queue.Queue()
    for _ in range(10):  # starts 10 threads
        threading.Thread(target=doRequest, args=(url_queue,)).start()

    threading.Thread(target=get_urls_from_db, args=(url_queue,)).start()
```

`get_urls_from_db` keeps reading URLs from database and adds the current list of URLs from database to the `url_queue` to be processed.

In `doRequest`, each iteration of the loop now grabs one url from the `url_queue` and processes it.

One thing to watch out for is adding URLs too quickly and processing can't keep up. Then the queue length will grow over time and consume lots of memory.

This is arguably better since now you do have great control over what URLs to process and have a fixed number of threads.

Comment: Oh thats actually very interesting way to do. What I was thinking to do was to play around with the variable `URLS` - basically updating that variable whenever we add/remove. To have something like this <https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/owodubobub.py>

Comment: What do you think about that approach if I might ask?

Comment: I think that would work for adding URLs, but not for removing them. Actually, there is a cleaner way. Let me add to the solution.

Comment: If you check inside doRequests - I have a if url not in URLS which will exit if its not in the URLS variable -> will remove it

Comment: oh that would work :)

Comment: But sure if you have any cleaner way this way.. I would like to see, maybe I could improve it?

Comment: But also im not sure if calling "database_urls()" could trigger recursion?

Comment: calling it inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` will not trigger recursion

Comment: Very interesting but im not sure if its any good to read database all the time? Isn't that a bad thing to do?

Comment: You are right. It’s not ideal to constantly reading from the database. Depending on how often your URL list changes, reading at some regular interval should be ok. Otherwise, you can use the `event` in method 1 to control update from database. Normally you just loop the last URL list from database. Then, whenever the database changes you can set the event, triggering the function grab the updated list.

Comment: I see I see, but what did you thought about the way I did it? I feel like it was pretty simple and could work the same way? - I could make it return sets instead to make the o(2) faster to check if its in dict or not

Comment: Yes your method works :) tho I would recommend have a fixed number of threads instead of tying the threads to urls. That would avoid having to terminate/spawn threads, which is harder to manage but can totally work.

Comment: Apprecaite everything for this evening/day. You have helped me alot and I do thank you for that.! wish you all the best

Comment: No problem. It was great problem and discussions! Good luck with your project!